# Cross process memory managment

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I wish to allocate data on a shared memory segment in one process and free it in another.

I allocate it in process 1 (Proc1) using the following line:
`new_Class* pData = managed_windows_shared_memory_segment.construct<new_Class>(anonymous_instance) ()`

I then convert the pointer to a handle `get_handle_from_address(pData)`, transfer it to the other process (Proc2) convert it back to a pointer `static_cast<new_Class*>managed_windows_shared_memory_segment.get_address_from_handle(handle)`and try to deallocate it there. (after Proc1 died i might add)

when i try to deallocate it in proc 2 with `destroy_ptr(pData)` 
I get annoying an annoying exception: "Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000000000"
and trying to use `deallocate(pData)` doesn't fare better.

when i deallocate from Proc1 all is well, it's just the deallocation from from Proc2 that appears problematic.

Any Ideas?

---

The problem was caused by a virtual destructor in a base class.
note to self: Don't use virtual functions on shared memory, the Virtual method table is NOT cross process.

I would like to thank Chad. He rightly pointed out that i should post relevant code which caused me to take a closer look at an obscure base class.

Comment: Objects created with `managed_memory_segment.construct<MyType>` should be deallocated with `managed_memory_segment.destroy<MyType>` or `managed_memory_segment.destroy_ptr`.  Without a small reproducable example (or more code to look at) no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Right you are, i'll try to add a more comprehensive example when i get back to the office tomorrow morning.  as to the "destroy<MyType>" suggestion, that apparently doesn't work for anonymous_instance. perhaps i should rethink my premise and move to named instances.

Answer (score 1):

I heartily suggest using smart pointers, as you would with non-interprocess allocations.

Of course, regular `shared_ptr` doesn't cut it unless the refcount/weakref are also allocated in the shared memory segment.

Luckily, Boost Interprocess comes fully charged with

- `boost::interprocess::shared_ptr<T>`
- `boost::interprocess::make_shared<T>(...)`

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/interprocess_smart_ptr.html#interprocess.interprocess_smart_ptr.shared_ptr

There are also `scoped_ptr<>`, `unique_ptr<>` and even an `intrusive_ptr<>` for all your peculiar needs :)